# Why is this class being involved in serialization

Tags: java, android

I am getting the following serialization error and I am trying to read my object that I saved to a file

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.testGame.scoreCard; Incompatible class (SUID): com.testGame.scoreCard: static final long serialVersionUID =-5895378336422852901L; but expected com.testGame.scoreCard: static final long serialVersionUID =0L;
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.verifyAndInit(ObjectInputStream.java:2376)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1658)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:683)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1799)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1956)
```

But what I don't get is why scoreCard is serialized in the first place? The class(object) that I am writing and reading is serialized and does not call or make use of scoreCard class. Why would it complain about that class? Is there a way to see why this scoreCard is involved? ( I am using eclipse btw)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that class that you are trying to restore depends indirectly on ScoreCard, through another class for example?

To see dependencies in Eclipse you can click on a class name or method name and press Ctrl+Shift+G, it will show you all the places where class or method is used.

Another way to discover dependencies is to click on a method name and press Ctrl+Alt+H, it will show you call graph that you can discover further.

Comment: Good point. I tried them and still cant find a connection. There is no way I can somehow debug this and see "variable/method" is requesting this class?

Comment: @Snake Remove `implements Serializable` from `ScoreCard` and re-test. You will now get a `NotSerializableException` when whoever serializes `ScoreCard` tries to do so, and the stack trace will tell you who that is.

Comment: That's the thing I dont have it serialized in the first place. When I test no issues, but I got this error from an ACRA report for an app in production

Comment: Try persisting your class with [Xstream][1]. It converts Object stream to XML this will let you see any dependencies.

[1] http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html

Comment: @Snake Therefore it must inherit from a class that implements Serializable. Try printing a stacktrace inside a private void writeObject() method in the class.

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps serializing an inner class of `ScoreCard`? They have secret references to the containing object.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but not inner class exist for scorecard. I guess I will have to wait to see if I get more crashes like that from production ( I am not seeing it locally)